# limits.conf modification doesn't work

Tags: su, ulimit

On a SLES 9 machine I added the line:

```
vi /etc/security/limits.conf
USERNAME        hard    cpu           70
```

but when I check it with "ulimit -a":

```
SERVER:~ # su USERNAME
USERNAME@SERVER:/root> ulimit -a | grep -i cpu
cpu time             (seconds, -t) unlimited
USERNAME@SERVER:/root> 
USERNAME@SERVER:/root> ulimit -Ha | grep -i cpu
cpu time             (seconds, -t) unlimited
USERNAME@SERVER:/root>
```

It still says "unlimited".

**Question**: What am I missing?

Comment: Out of curiosity, has USERNAME successfully used more than 70min of CPU time?

Comment: how to test this? or how can I get this as info to the question? :O

Comment: Old question, but does the PAM configuration for `su` include `pam_limits.so`? If it doesn't then the only way to test is a fresh login.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an `/etc/pam.d/su`? On some systems, such as Debian Squeeze (at least), processing of limits configuration is disabled for `su`.

For example, inside `/etc/pam.d/su`, you may see something like this:

```
# Sets up user limits, please uncomment and read /etc/security/limits.conf
# to enable this functionality.
# (Replaces the use of /etc/limits in old login)
# session    required   pam_limits.so
```

If `session    required   pam_limits.so` is commented out or missing, uncomment or add it, and see if that fixes the problem.